# Placement of delete icon on applied filters

Tags: filter, web, faceted-search

With regard to faceted search on the web, why do some sites implement the delete (i.e. 'x') icon of applied filters to the left of the text versus the right.

For example, LinkedIn Job Search does it this way. In the image below the 'x' is to the left of "Past Month", as opposed to the more traditional right.

Is there some good reason for this, or research indicating that it's better?

[image: Applied Filters on LinkedIn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it does not matter at all as long as it is clear to the User that they can remove particular filter by pressing it. A counter example from here, at Stack Exchange:

[image]

However, one argument suggesting that the icon should be on the right would be touch devices, where most Users, operating the interface with their right hand, would not cover the tag itself when deleting it.

Comment: What happens if users are left handed? In my opinion this sort of information is highly irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with the siding not really mattering. The only thing to emphasize is which ever OP decides to go with would **have to be consistent throughout the application.**

Comment: Then the control is slightly less usable for them. And as there is less left handed Users than the right handed ones, and it is never possible to address all the possible cases, this only confirms the fact that placing the x on the right is reasonable.

Comment: Yes, fully agree with consistency.

Comment: I just don't think that's a fair thing to say when designing because it's been proven that placement on this sort of arbitrary icon/button/whatever is important. The more important thing here is consistency. Take a read here from the NNGroup: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok/

Comment: That is a very good point, +1 for it. However, this kind of tags is not as common pattern we interact with as [OK] and [Cancel] buttons are. So external consistency (with the platform a particular User uses) may be another thing to consider, but as many other ones, not pointing directly what the right choice is. There could be more: as Jakob says, there are arguments for both (and it would work the same way here): natural reading order (Remove apples) or conclusion based order (Apples? No, remove it.). Still, "it's simply not worth it to conduct sufficiently elaborate research".

Answer (score 1):

One argument for this would be because the tags are also aligned to the left side; once you delete the first tag, the second tags delete button will go to the exact same position. Making it easy to delete multiple tags.

Comment: I admit that while this may be a corner case, it indeed increases the usability a little bit. I often benefit from the fixed placement of the tabs close button in a browser.